# Can't get redis data, but can write to redis

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I have the following set up to set and check values from redis

```
var ttl = '60';

function someRandom(value, callback){

   client.exists(value, function check(err, data){
      if(data === 0){
         //do functionality
         client.set(value,'nx','ex',ttl, function(err,data){
           callback(null);
         });

      }else{
        client.incr(value);
        callback(null);
      }
   })

}
```

Now from above, there is no issue in setting value. According to the `exists` function, if the value exists, it returns "1" and otherwise it returns "0". But when i check for the similar value in redis it returns as "0" when it already exists.

**Adding more info**

When i check for the value on the second attempt, the **err=null** and **data=0**, when it should be "1" as the value already exists.

Also using the **redis-cli** commands returns 1

The ioredis config looks like the following

```
db0: new Redis({
    sentinels: endpoints,
    name: REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME,
    db: 0
}),

db1: new Redis({
    sentinels: endpoints,
    name: REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME,
    db: 1
}),


sub: new Redis({
    sentinels: endpoints,
    name: REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME,
    db: 0
}),

pub: new Redis({
    sentinels: endpoints,
    name: REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME,
    db: 0
})
```

where senitelname is **mymaster**

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail.  What happens using `redis-cli`, does it work fine?  What values are you getting in `data`?  Are you sure `node-redis` will return integer 0?  It might be different than the `cli`.

Comment: @Russbear sorry i am not using node-redis, using ioredis and using redis-cli its returns 1 for the key

Comment: You need to give more info about what values you're getting from `err` and `data`, what the CLI is giving you, and what your config of `ioredis` looks like.

Comment: @Russbear i have more info in the original post

Comment: @Russbear i actually figured what the issue is, it was the way the value was being passed into redis methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you just wrong to call redis.set:

```
client.set(value,'nx','ex',ttl, function(err,data){
    callback(null);
});
```

You set the key(the value of "value")'s value to 'nx', with ttl "60", next time you incr it, because it is not a integer, the result is 1, with ttl less than "60", if ttl less than 1, the key is gone, this is what your see.

See documention: http://redis.io/commands/set

Suggest to run the command manually with redis-cli command tool on your redis database, and see what will happen.